# PHP string as array key for mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xampp, key

I am trying to use a variable (string) as array key for a mysql select query in PHP script.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$newskill="'".$skill."_!skill'";
//$newskill="'Working_!skill'"; //Will be written into the var in the line above

$skill = array();
$time = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getSkills))
{
   $skill[] = $row[$newskill];
   $time[] = $row['updated_at'];
}
```

I am getting this error:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: 'Working_!skill' in **....\htdocs\skill\skilldiagram.php** on line **71**

But it works this way: Nothing changed but the content of the variable is printed hardcoded into the source code. This way it works perfectly fine.

```
$skill = array();
$time = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getSkills))
{
   $skill[] = $row['Working_!skill'];
   $time[] = $row['updated_at'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the literal quotes in `$newskill`. It should be:

```
$newskill=$skill."_!skill";
```

Comment: Works ty. That was fast and I feel like an idiot now :)